# What value we'll receive if we apply std::cout to a pointer to member

Tags: c++, pointers

We can get an address representation of an object located in memory by applying

```
std::cout << &obj << std::endl
```

I'm trying to do the same with a pointer-to-member type.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct X
{
    bool b;
    int a;
};
int X::* a =&X::a;
bool X::* b = &X::b;
X x;

int main()
{
    cout << a << endl << b; //1
                            //1
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/994b8f7f96756842)**

You see I received `1`. What is just `1`?
Or must I mention a `pointer-to-member` as just a type that doesn't directly bound to a "just" pointer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there's no overload for `operator<<` that takes a pointer to member directly, `a` and `b` are implicitly converted to `bool`, for which an overload exists. The semantics of this standard conversion are as follows:

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a
>   prvalue of type `bool`. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to `false`;
>   any other value is converted to `true`.

So `a` and `b` both become `true` and the value printed is therefore `1`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    cout << std::boolalpha << a << endl << b; //1
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83cd563764076d8d)

You'll see you're getting "true" now. It's just the implicit conversion to `bool` firing.